# Display helpButton next to the label?

Tags: visualforce

How can I put helpButton next to the label? as you seen in the screen shot the helpButton is on top of the check-box and I try to place style with margin=left but does not make any diff.

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem > 
                <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Employee__c.fields.Is_Stauts__c.Label}"/>
                     <span class="helpButtonOn" id="Name-_help" >  
                        <img src="/s.gif" alt="" class="helpOrb"   />
                        <script type="text/javascript">sfdcPage.setHelp('Name', 'Ex. <br/> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br/>');</script>
                    </span>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Employee__c.Is_Status__c}"> </apex:inputField>   
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Your markup shouldn't compile...you can have at most two child components to `pageBlockSectionItem`.

Comment: i did not get any compile error, try it on your sandbox :)

Comment: I did, that's how I caught it in the first place.

Comment: Even i got the same, I wrapped it in panel grid, and i get the same overlap of helpbubble and checkbox as per nick.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the `helpText` attribute on `pageBlockSectionItem`.

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem
    helpText="{!$ObjectType.Employee__c.fields.Is_Stauts__c.InlineHelpText}">
```

As the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockSectionItem.htm) states:

> Note that help text only displays if the showHeader attribute of the parent page is set to true.

Comment: i have a long text with multiple lines and I tried first to have that with break lines in the HelpText but that does not show my help text the way i wanted. Have you tried with multiple lines with break in the helpText?

Comment: Please try this, http://burnignorance.com/salesforce-tips/apply-line-breaks-in-help-text-2/

Comment: @AnuragA: look at my question I'm using similar code but the problem I'm having is that helpButton is sitting on top of the checkbox, read my question please.

Comment: @NickKahn, try <span class="helpButtonOn" id="Name-_help" style="right:11px">

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question initially. I changed my answer above. See if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete visualforce markup with CSS. In the screens you can see the help bubble and checkbox is properly aligned. Also you can see the long help text with multiple lines with line breaks achieved through CSS.

```
<apex:page standardController="Book__c">
    <style>
        .vfHelpText a {
            position:relative;
        }
        .vfHelpText a span {
            display: none;
        }
        .vfHelpText a:hover span {
            display: block;
            position:absolute;
            top:1.25em;
            padding:2px 5px;
            left:-15em; width:15em;
            z-index:100;
            border:1px solid orange;
            background-color:#FEFDB9;
            color:black;
        }
    </style>    
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="My Content" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section" columns="2">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Book__c.fields.Is_Status__c.Label}"/>
                        <span class="vfHelpText">
                            <apex:outputLink value="javascript:return false;" styleClass="helpButtonOn">
                                <img src="/s.gif" alt="" class="helpOrb" />
                                <span>'Name', 'Ex. <br/> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br/></span>
                            </apex:outputLink>
                        </span>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Book__c.Is_Status__c}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Screen 1**

[image]

**Screen 2**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, misunderstood your issue initially. Try adding the following css.

```
.helpButton, .helpButtonOn {
    top: -1px;
    left: -5px;
}
```